# How do you split a big message in different lines in python telebot?

Tags: python, formatting, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

So hey. My previous question was not well received so I'll try to do better this time.

One of my help commands for the bot sends them a list of commands that they can do. Here's the code for the specific part of the problem:

```
def help_command(update, context):
    update.message.reply_text("What do you need my help in?")
    update.message.reply_text("/commandhelp - Know my commands")
    update.message.reply_text("/helpmegetapartner - Get advice on getting a partner")

dp.add_handler(CommandHandler("jhelp", help_command))
```

Now, I will with time add more commands, which may not fall under the given list. But there's no way (that I know of) to send the same message but in one single one, along with line breaks. This method will bombard them with messages and make them hate me. Please help!

Comment: Test using `\n` in the end of each message and combine all messages in one string.

Comment: in python as in a lot of programming languages, "\n" is the line break. So you should be able to do  update.message.reply_text("What do you need my help in? \n commandhelp - Know my commands \n/helpmegetapartner - Get advice on getting a partner")

Comment: That worked but it's hard to manage a long line of code. Is there a way to write the code in separate lines for the same function?

Comment: @Ezriel_S that sort of worked but managing a really long line of code can be hard. Any way to split the code (and only the code) into separate lines but still have the intended effect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use triple quotes like that :

```py
help_command_text = """What do you need my help in?
/commandhelp - Know my commands
/helpmegetapartner - Get advice on getting a partner
/anothercommand ...
"""
```

And then

```py
update.message.reply_text(help_command_text)
```